# Run exiftool across multiple spefici file types

Tags: exiftool

is there a way to use `exiftool` command on all files with specific extensions inside a folder?

E.g.

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -all= *.jpg *.png *.jpeg
```

The problem of the command above is that it gives me:

```
no matches found: *.png
```

because there are not `.png` images inside my folder, but I want the command to run anyway on all files with other extensions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`-ext` (extension) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ext-EXT---ext-EXT--extension) and a dot to indicate the current directory, e.g. `exiftool -overwrite_original -all= -ext jpg -ext jpeg -ext png .`

This option becomes especially import when you add the recurse options (`-r`) as wild cards won't work like that when you recurse (see [Common Mistake #2](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M2)).